# Is there a name for the "antisymmetric Cauchy-Schwarz inequality"?

Tags: inequality

From [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)
$$
|\mathbf{a}|^2 |\mathbf{b}|^2  = (\mathbf {a \cdot b})^2 + |\mathbf {a \times b}|^2
$$
the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) follows
$$
|\mathbf{a}|^2 |\mathbf{b}|^2  \geq (\mathbf {a \cdot b})^2 
$$
However one could also derive the following inequality
$$
|\mathbf{a}|^2 |\mathbf{b}|^2  \geq  |\mathbf {a \times b}|^2
$$
which is based on the "antisymmetric" part of Lagrange's identity. Does this last inequality have a name? Is it used somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of [Hadamard's determinant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about dimension $3$, notice that the interpretation is very simple: 
$$|\bf a\times b|\le |a|\cdot|b|$$ says that the volume of the parallelogram defined by $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ is at most the product of the lengths of the sides.

Probably because of this it would be a bit too much to give it a name, even more when it is only a very particular case of the inequality
$$
\lvert\det A|\le\prod_{i=1}^n\|v_i\|
$$
if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are the columns of $A$.